# Как отправить массив на jquery ajax?

Tags: ajax, php

Вот он фрагмент моего кода:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/ajax.feedback.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'author=' + author + '&mail=' + mail + '&subject=' + subject + '&text=' + text +
            '&checkbox[1]=' + checkbox[1] + '&checkbox[2]=' + checkbox[2] + '&checkbox[3]=' + checkbox[3] + '&checkbox[4]=' + checkbox[4] + '&checkbox[5]=' + checkbox[5] +
            '&checkbox[6]=' + checkbox[6] + '&checkbox[7]=' + checkbox[7] + '&checkbox[8]=' + checkbox[8] + '&checkbox[9]=' + checkbox[9],

        success: ...
```

Как проще сделать? Просто отправить массив? (и как его прочитать потом в php? если есть какие-либо особенности) В гугле - не понятно - надо объект вроде создавать, использовать json. На практике ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

там есть пример

```
$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });
```

для вашего случая должно быть что-то такое:

```
$.post('ajax/ajax.feedback.php',
    {'author':author,'mail':mail,'subject':subject,'text':text,'checkbox[]':checkbox},
    function (html) { success ... 
    });
```

а еще проще, можно так:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

на сервере все это дело будет в массиве $_POST;
достаточно вывести его на зкран print_r($_POST) и все станет ясно

Comment: Начал с первого варианта - все довольно просто. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с использованием JSON:

```
var author = document.getElementById("author").value;
...
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax.feedback.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({author:author, id:id, mail:mail}),
    success: function(data) {}    
});
```

приём данных осуществляется через массив $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, есть варианты:
 1. Склеить все в строку с разделителем (в строке все вхождения разделителя поменять на html-эквиваленты) и отправить все одним параметром. А на сервере сделать explode(); .
 2. Почитать тут - http://www.simplecoding.org/otpravka-dannyx-v-formate-json-s-pomoshhyu-javascript-i-jquery.html . Вроде как, все доступно написано.
В принципе, способы похожи.